PUT Request does not work in NEXT 14, at Production
When I run the next application in localy development mode, it work perfectly. Also PUT request work good. When I build it, and run the production build then the put request did not work. It give response 405. But it work in develop mode. After I build it create problem, and does not allow PUT request. Here is my put request route :
export const PUT = async (request) => {
    try {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const name = data.get('name');
        const email = data.get('email');
        const phone = data.get('phone');
        const message = data.get('message');
        const file = data.get('image');

        let cookie = request.cookies.get('token');
        if (!cookie) {
            return Response.json({ error: 'unothorized access' }, { status: 401 })
        }
        const { user_name } = await verifyToken(cookie?.value);

        await VerifyAdmin(user_name);

        const updatedData = [name, email, phone, message];
        let sqlCmd = `update directors set 
                        name = ?,
                        email = ?,
                        phone = ?,
                        message = ?`

        if (file && file.size > 0) {
            const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
            const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);

            // Ensure the 'peoples' directory exists within 'public'
            await ensureDir(publicDir);

            // Construct the file path
            const fileName = Date.now() + '-' + file.name;
            const filePath = join(publicDir, fileName);

            // Write file to the public directory
            await writeFile(filePath, buffer);

            sqlCmd += `, image = ?`
            updatedData.push('/peoples/' + fileName);
        }

        sqlCmd += " where position = 'chairman' "
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.query(sqlCmd, updatedData, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })
                }
                resolve({ result })
            })
        });

        return Response.json({ message: 'update successfully' }, { status: 200 })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return Response.json({ error: 'something went wrong, try again' }, { status: 500 })
    }
}

Below the route.js file location in app directory :

I want to make PUT request allowed in production build. But it's not happens. How I do it now ?

I already solve it. I just add another function in route.js file to allow PUT request explicitly :
export function methods() {
    return ['GET', 'PUT'];
}

now it's work in production :)
